# Swiper js respect image aspect ratio

Tags: css, swiper.js

In this Swiper demo, how can I make it always respect the original image's aspect ratio? (in this case square 1:1 ratio)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-30-thumbs-gallery-myq76w?file=index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style.css you can adjust the `.swiper-slide` class to use background-size contain instead of cover if you don't mind the empty space on the sides of the image.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-30-thumbs-gallery-s2knwx?file=style.css

```
.swiper-slide {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```